# How to delete folder or file in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin which require user to remove (or delete) a directory or file.

## After initiating the WP_Filesystem like this

```
function filesystem_init($form_url, $method, $context, $fields = null) {
global $wp_filesystem;
/* get credentials */
if (false === ($creds = request_filesystem_credentials($form_url, $method, false, $context, $fields))) {
return false;
}

if (!WP_Filesystem($creds)) {
/* incorrect connection data - ask for credentials again, now with error message */
request_filesystem_credentials($form_url, $method, true, $context);
return false;
}
return true; //successfully initiated
}
```

## When the form is posted I have done this to remove a directory with one single file

`WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/myp/mfold/selectedfolder/index.php';`

```
function RemoveData($form_url){
global $wp_filesystem;
check_admin_referer('ToRemoveData');
$ToRemove = $_POST['dirToGo']; 
$form_fields = array('dirToGo');
$method = ''; 
$targetFolder= WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/myp/mfold/'.$ToRemove; //target folder
$form_url = wp_nonce_url($form_url, 'ToRemoveData'); //page field with nonce value
if(!filesystem_init($form_url, $method, $targetFolder, $form_fields))
return false;
if($wp_filesystem->is_dir($targetFolder))
{   
$wp_filesystem->rmdir($targetFolder);
//WP_Filesystem_Base::delete($targetFolder);        
return " Successful !";
}
else
{
return new WP_Error('writing_error', 'Cannot Remove');
}//return error object
}//close function
```

**This function return Success but the folder or the directory is not deleting.**

Any idea anyone Thanks

Comment: The function is returning success, because it's checking if the file is a directory, not if it successfully removed it.

Comment: yes understand that up to that portion but just to remove the directory is the issues

Answer (score 2):

```
$wp_filesystem->delete($target_folder, true);
```

Use this code to remove directory.